# Can we share mixing jug/beaker for developer, fixer and stop bath?

Tags: film, developing, chemicals, fixer, stop-bath

I have developer, fixer, and stop bath concentrate. 
To make solution we usually use mixing jug/beaker.

Should we dedicate one mixing jug for each one of the component above?
Or can we just use one for three of them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the same container and mixing utensils and thermometer etc. for mixing. This is valid provided you take care to rinse well between solutions. Also, the items must not be porous (ceramic etc.). If you are in doubt regarding your ability to properly rinse, you can still proceed if containers and utensils are seasoned. To season, save small quantities of the fluids for this purpose. Rinse thoroughly then season with a dilute solution. Suppose you are to prepare a developer solution and are in doubt as to the cleanliness. Rinse with a dilute solution of developer (may be used or otherwise expired), then rinse with clean water. This act will prevent contamination due to improper cleansing.

Answer (score 2):

While you *can* use the same mixing jug, provided some precautions as Alan Marcus mentions...I'm somewhat confused as to the *why* of this. Ideally, you've got separate storage containers for your mixed stop, fix, and perma-wash (and photo Flo, if you use it). You can measure your chemicals in your measuring device of choice and then add to your storage container filled with the awaiting water<sup>1</sup>. Doing this, the only thing that you reuse is the measuring device.

In addition to what Marcus said about rinsing and seasoning methods - go in order of development. Mix up your stop batch, then fix, then perma-wash. Even if you were drastically sloppy, a little bit of leftover fix in the perma-wash won't kill a full batch, (though you may reduce the life of the batch). Going the other way around can really mess things up for you.

---

<sub>1: Adding strong acids/bases and water together releases a lot of heat. Because of this, it's a good idea to add acid/base to water (instead of water to acid/base) and to go slowly. Now, photo chemistry is fairly benign - but I'd encourage the practice anyway, along with good chemistry lab practices in general, in case you decide to get into more caustic photo chemistry later. You'll have a good base of second-nature skills.</sub>

Comment: thanks. So reusing 'measuring device' has no harm?

Comment: @neversaint none what-so-ever. I use the same one to measure all of my chemicals  with a solid rinse in between. Like Alan said, if you're not confident in your rinsing, you can add a little of whatever chemical you're on, move it around, and rinse again. Even if you were terribly sloppy, some stop in the fix won't do anything. Some fix in the perma-wash will lessen it's lifespan, but otherwise not cause issue.

Comment: Consider that all chemicals will eventually pass through the same development tank (with appropriate rinsing). Mixing directly in the storage containers reduces risk of accidental contamination and amount of equipment that needs to be cleaned later.

Comment: @xiota film shooters: I'm going to take this image and then spend *at least* another two days between developing and perfecting a print. Also film shooters: too damn lazy to clean more than one beaker. ;-)

Comment: Note: "Mixing in the storage containers" being safe has a catch: Powdered chemicals like ID-11 or D76 _must_ be mixed in a container large enough for the entire kit volume. Ie, Do NOT try to split the powder of a 5L kit across 20 250ml bottles before mixing with water. Mix the whole 5L as a single unit and let rest before dividing into the smaller storage bottles.

Comment: @TheLuckless I've always heard the "always mix the whole bag" - but never really heard a rationale for it. Is it possible for the powder mix to separate to some degree such that any given scoop isn't exactly a good amount of all the various components?

Comment: @TheLuckless That's why the solution in the first container burns the film, while the other 19 don't seem to do anything.

Comment: @Hueco yes, multiple mostly white powders of similar grain size make it impossible to reliably sub-divide and keep the chemical ratios balanced. Strong arguments for letting ID-11/D76 'mature' for 24 hours before breaking down into smaller storage bottles. - Chemists tell me it allows time for the initial mixing and reactions to settle evenly across all the water, and they're the ones with the fancy coats, so I'll trust them.